# Find details about stopping trigger

Tags: sql, t-sql, triggers, sql-server-2012

Maybe question isn't appropriate for this place, but I will tried:

I have five triggers on one table, and after certain time (about five months) I realize that two of them are disabled.

Is there any chance to find time when this triggers are stopped, and who do that, if are manually disabled?

If question doesn't belong here, please advise me where to put.

Thanks a lot

Comment: I don't believe you can retrospectively discover this information. It may be possible to track these changes, but you'd have to implement/turn on such tracking and then in the *future* you would be able to answer such a question. I've voted to close to to redirect question to [dba](http://dba.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a query that will get you most of the information you want, if you run it in a specific database it will list all the tables that have triggers on, the name of the trigger, whether or not it is disabled or not and when it was last created/modified.

SQL server doesn't log who enabled/disabled the trigger, I think you'd have to set up an audit if you need that information:

```
SELECT  DB_NAME() AS [Database] ,
        OBJECT_NAME([parent_object_id]) AS [table] ,
        name AS [Trigger] ,
        OBJECTPROPERTY([object_id], 'ExecIsTriggerDisabled') AS [Disabled],
        create_date,
        modify_date
FROM    sys.objects
WHERE   [type] = 'TR'
```

Comment: Darn! I was writing something like this, but our internet was down. You could also use `sys.triggers`.

Comment: sys.triggers is a good one to know about as that allows you to distinguish between DML and DDL triggers too